generate a graph between 15k+ strings of recipe ingredients
you know real world data is messy, and i have an interesting problem that i cannot find the solution to or cannot find the right keywords to search.
so i have about 15k+ recipe ingredients written in a magnitude of different forms for
[
"6-8 boneless chicken thighs",
"2 carrots (peeled and sliced)",
"2 stalks of celery (sliced)",
"1 small-medium onion (diced)",
"2 cloves garlic (minced)",
"2 medium tomatoes (diced)",
"12 baby potatoes (left whole or cut in half)",
"1 3/4 cup chicken stock"
]

what i need to do is based on the recipe above find other recipes that have similar ingredients so that the user wouldn't need to buy 1000 ingredients if i give them 3 recipes. It also shouldn't confuse with for example 1kg of chicken and 100ml of chicken stock, but also onions, onions (diced), and onions should be the same. can there a graphing algorithm that makes weighted graphs between these strings that i can search through. my question is what kind of algorithms are out there to solve this kind of problem?

After you have settled what is equal and what is not (you'll have to create a mapping for all that), this becomes Maximizing selected sets so that their union is less than k?, which is NP-hard, meaning there is no known solution that has a polynomial time complexity.

I just asked ChatGPT: Name the main ingredient in, "6-8 boneless chicken thighs". Just give me the name, not an explanation. I really can't think of anything that will do nearly as well as API calls to an LLM like that.
